# FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie doesn't [Authorize] in MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, authorization

I created a brand new ASP.NET MVC 5 project to test the `[Authorize]` attribute with `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie`. I simply set a cookie in one action (in my Home controller):

```
    public ActionResult About()
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie("someUser", false);
```

And I limit access to another:

```
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Contact()
    {
```

When I launch my web page and navigate to `/home/contact`, I am correctly redirected to a login page. Then I go to `/home/about`, get my cookie, and go back to the contact page. But I'm still redirected to the login page -- the cookie does not authenticate/authorize me.

In the debugger, `HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated == false` when I load the About page multiple times (that is to say, it never sees me as being authenticated even after setting an auth cookie).

Is there some extra step that must be done here? I shouldn't need to set my own IPrincipal for basic authentication, should I?

Comment: MVC5 no longer using forms authentication, check your web.config for <modules>
  <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
</modules>. if you want to use it follow this article, you can use owin to handle it. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/07/03/understanding-owin-forms-authentication-in-mvc-5.aspx

Comment: After some research on OWIN, it seems this is the better option, seeing as how Microsoft is going in this direction for MVC 6. I used [ASP.NET Identity Without A Database](https://github.com/leeenglestone/ASP.NET-Identity-Without-a-Database) as an example for how to authenticate and authorize. It's a good deal more complex than a simple `SetAuthCookie`, but it seems more future-proof.

Comment: Man, that's a bunch of doo doo.  Why does Microsoft do that crap?

Comment: @DSR , I can't find
`<modules>
    <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
</modules>`

in my web.config

Answer (score 57):

from web.config remove:

```
<modules>
  <!--<remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule" />-->
</modules>
```

or simples remove the line

in web.config

Comment: Saved my life and many hours that were almost wasted... thanks!!

Comment: In my case this was `<remove name="FormsAuthentication" />`

Comment: Why is this not marked as the correct answer? Saved my life as well :)

Comment: The time!!!  It's gone forever.  8 hours to be precise.  I'm glad I found this or more time gone.  This fixed everything in under 2 minutes!

Comment: It's so epic when experienced developers write 5-7 lines of code to solve the problem and then one person comes silently to destroy their answers. Haha! Wonderful Solution. You just saved my day man. Many thanks! :)

Comment: Man you saved my life, I spent too many hours with this bug ... thank you so much!

Answer (score 16):

EDIT: I did not know MVC5 defaulted new projects to having Forms Authentication removed (the module is removed) so make sure you also check DSR's comment under your originial post in conjuncture with all of this.

Check your web.config and look for the authentication section, it should look something like this,

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="..." cookieless="UseCookies" />
</authentication>
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1d3t3c61%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

The default cookieless value is "UseDeviceProfile" which means that cookies are used if the browser reports that it supports cookies, otherwise cookies are not used and it uses values in the querystring to maintain an authenticated state (which need to be retained accross postbacks).

Secondly, make sure cookies are on in your browser.  If the device/browser does not support cookies or they are turned off then SetAuthCookie will make changes to the url, but you have to redirect the browser after the call to SetAuthCookie using...

```
FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(String, Boolean)...
```

That method redirects the page to it's destination after authentication with SetAuthCookie.  RedirectFromLoginPage will put the required attributes in the url query to maintain the login session accross postbacks.  If you do your own redirects on the site here and there you will need to maintain that url query parameter accross postbacks your self by checking if the current user is authenticated with HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated.

In order to send your users to the login page you should be using

```
FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage()
```

That method will add a returnUrl parameter to the query string, which the later function "RedirectFromLoginPage" will redirect back to after being authenticated.

If you block access to users or roles with location elements in your web.config to paths and resources Forms Authentication handles the redirection to the login page automatically when an un-authenticated user attempts to access them.

```
  <location path="SomeFolderOnYourSite">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?"/>
        <allow roles="Administrators"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <location path="SomeFolderOnYourSite">
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <deny users="?"/>
    <allow roles="Administrators"/>
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

is like it's not working for me when am using same code with small change it's working `**<location path="~/SomeFolderOnYourSite">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?"/>
        <allow roles="Administrators"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>**`

Answer (score 0):

Commenting these lines in the file web.config, with FrameWork 4.5.2 worked for me. I use the active directory for login.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577)

Answer (score -1):

Specifying wrong value for `domain` attribute of forms tag can cause this too.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms domain="localhost" ... />
</authentication>
```

Comment: Specifying wrong domain itself will not run the page. There will be run time error.