# Wrong authentication in asp mvc 4

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have login page and I want to redirect to same page if the password or user name are invalid. 
This is the code in login post:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel lm, string returnUrl)
{
    using (WorkLayer dal = new WorkLayer())
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
           // UserManager UM = new UserManager();
           //   string password = UM.GetUserPassword(ULV.LoginName);
            string password = dal.Users.GetUserInfo(lm.UserName).HashPassword.ToString();

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user login or password provided is incorrect.");

            else
            {

                if (lm.HashPassword.Equals(password))
                {
                    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(lm.UserName, false);
                    return RedirectToAction("AdminPanel");
                } 
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "The password provided is incorrect.");
                    return RedirectToAction("Login");
                }
            }
        } 
    }
    return View(lm);

}
```

And the code in Action Admin:

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult AdminPanel()
{
    return View();
}
```

But every time when I enter correctly my username and password I receive:

HTTP Error 401.0 - Unauthorized
You do not have permission to view this directory or page.
Most likely causes:

```
The authenticated user does not have access to a resource needed to process the request.
```

Comment: What would be the point of adding a `ModelStateError` and then redirecting. You need to return the view (`return View(lm);`)

Comment: Password is not equal to hashed password (right? aren't you storing plain password...)

Comment: For now - yes. Then I gonna write procedure for hashing password.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie doesn't \[Authorize\] in MVC 5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26613421/formsauthentication-setauthcookie-doesnt-authorize-in-mvc-5)

Comment: I don't have roles now because It is very small website.

Comment: If you are sure (use the debugger) that `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie` is being called then this is probably a duplicate of the question I posted above (*which has nothing to do with roles*).

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing an `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute on your `Login` Action. The `AccountController` usually has an `[Authorize]` attribute which means you need to allow anonymous on the actions you want requests that have not been authenticated as yet to be served.

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel lm, string returnUrl) {...}
```

Also as mentioned by @StephenMuecke in the comments you don't need to redirect on error/invalid credentials. Just let the action flow to completion.

Here is the refactored `Login` action

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel lm, string returnUrl) {
    using (WorkLayer dal = new WorkLayer()) {
        if (ModelState.IsValid) {
            string password = dal.Users.GetUserInfo(lm.UserName).HashPassword.ToString();

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(password) && lm.HashPassword.Equals(password)) {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(lm.UserName, false);
                return RedirectToAction("AdminPanel");
            } else {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user login or password provided is incorrect.");                    
            }
        } 
    }
    return View(lm);
}
```

Comment: It's working for uncorrect username or password, but not for right ones. Again I see the same message.