# Set authentification in asp net core (asp net 5)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I need the ability to authentificate my user from code in test like this

```
var identity = new GenericIdentity("ausov@fsb.ru", "UserId");
Thread.CurrentPrincipal = new GenericPrincipal(identity, null);
```

Or like this

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, rememberMe);
```

But these methods not working in asp net 5.

Comment: Add a question and more context why you want to do this.

Answer (score 10):

To get this to work in ASP.NET Core, first, use NuGet to add Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies

In Startup.cs, add this to the Configure method:

```
  app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
  {
    AuthenticationScheme = "PutANameHere",
    LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login/"),
    AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
    AutomaticChallenge = true
  });
```

Then call this to login:

```
  var userClaims = new List<Claim>
    {
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, userName)     
    };

  var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(userClaims, "local"));
  HttpContext.Authentication.SignInAsync("PutANameHere", principal);
```

For more information on this, check this out:
https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authentication/cookie.html

Comment: await HttpContext.Authentication.SignInAsync("MyCookieMiddlewareInstance", principal);
                var p = User.Identity.Name; After authentification user name is null

Comment: what exactly does the nuget do? i did notice the extension doesn't seem to be a part of it. it compiles well without the nuget however it doesn't run without the nuget

Answer (score -1):

The `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie` method is part of the `System.Web.Security` namespace in ASP.NET, which is included in the .NET Framework. Therefore, you can use the `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie` method in your ASP.NET application without any additional packages or libraries.

Have you tried this : [FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie doesn't [Authorize] in MVC 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26613421/formsauthentication-setauthcookie-doesnt-authorize-in-mvc-5)