# How to do authentication in asp.Net MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, authentication

I have HomeController on which index method have [Authorize] so if not login than it redirect to login action and after successful login it redirect to Patient Home controller.But Problem is authentication is not working.

```
    [Authorize]
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Login(User user)
    {
       User usr = _logingService.Login(user.Email,user.Password);
        if(usr!=null)
        {
            Patient pat = _patientService.GetPatient(usr.Id);
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(pat.Name, false);
            if (usr.Role == "Patient")
            {

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { Area = "Patient" });
            }
            else
            {
            }

        }

        return View();
    }
```

Now from Database I am getting actual value but after When It redirect to Patient Index action, there I used again [Authorize] but it redirect again to Login Page

```
    [Authorize]
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: See here - have you removed the `FormsAuthenticationModule` from your web.config?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26613421/formsauthentication-setauthcookie-doesnt-authorize-in-mvc-5

Comment: Thanks Sir now its working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from web.config remove:

```
<modules>
    <!--<remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule" />-->
</modules>
```

or simples remove the line in web.config and it will work fine.