# Adding [Authorize] in controller resulted in Error 401.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis

I'm doing a simple user signup web project. Whenever I add the [Authorize] in the controller and subsequently created the view from it, when I run the code, it produced HTTPS 401.0 Unauthorized Error. If I removed it, it runs, but not producing the result I wanted exactly.

In my `Account Controller`, I had this:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult SignUp(UserSignUpView USV)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                UserManager UM = new UserManager();
                if (!UM.IsLoginNameExist(USV.LoginName))
                {
                    UM.AddUserAccount(USV);
                    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(USV.FirstName, false);
                    return RedirectToAction("Welcome", "Home");

                }
                else ModelState.AddModelError("", "Login Name already taken.");
            }
            return View();
        }
```

In my `Home` controller, I had this:

```
namespace MVC5FileRealWorld.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Home
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [Authorize]
        public ActionResult Welcome()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

I created a view by add view from right click the `Welcome()`

Below is my `Welcome` class:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Welcome";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Hi <b>@Context.User.Identity.Name</b>! Welcome to my first MVC 5 Web App!</h2>
```

After the user successfully registered (i.e. data successfully saved into the database),

It should display 'Hi XXX! Welcome to my first MVC5 Web App!'

But now if I added [Authorize] and generate a view, then it will just display the HTTP 401.0 error.
If I removed [Authorize] and regenerate another view (the same name as previous one), it will just display 'Hi! Welcome to my first MVC5 Web App!'. This line of code `@Context.User.Identity.Name` just doesn't seem to work also for the latter case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the 401 when you're not authorized while trying to access a "protected" resource.

If you're not authorized: `@Context.User.Identity.Name` will return an empty string.

So far, this is what you are experiencing.

You show the code of "SignUp", which creates a authentication cookie, which should authorize the user. Next to that; you should have a "log in" form on which a user can log in.

---

So, login with an existing user, or signup with a new one. If tho cookie persists you'll be authorized.

---

If this doesn't work; most likely your authorization/authentication pipeline isn't setup correctly.

---

As a last resort you can try:

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(USV.FirstName, true);
```

or maybe you need to check your `web.config`

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="..." cookieless="UseCookies" />
</authentication>

<!-- more stuff -->

<modules>
   <!-- removed module -->
   <!--<remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule" />-->
</modules>
```

see: [FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie doesn't [Authorize] in MVC 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26613421/formsauthentication-setauthcookie-doesnt-authorize-in-mvc-5)